# Is there a way to speed up execution time of this firebase cloud function?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have following firebase cloud function (js sdk) which executes correctly. I'd like to know if there's a way to speed up execution time. This function takes on average 250ms with a userGroups collection of 10 items. I expect to run this function with a userGroups collection of arround 500 items. Any help is appreciated!

```
.ref('users/{userId}/mood/')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const userId = context.params.userId
  const beforeData = change.before.val(); 
  const afterData = change.after.val(); 
  const afterDataValue = parseInt(afterData.value || 0);
  const afterDataElement = afterData.element;
  const beforeDataValue = parseInt(beforeData.value || 0);
  const beforeDataElement = beforeData.element;

  const userGroups = admin.database().ref('/users/' + userId + '/groups/location/Items');

  const groupMood = userGroups.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
      const itemId = childSnapshot.key
      const currentElementValueRef = admin.database().ref('/groups/location/Items/' + itemId + '/mood/' + afterDataElement + '/value');
      const currentElementVoteCountRef = admin.database().ref('/groups/location/Items/' + itemId + '/mood/' + afterDataElement + '/votecount');


      if(beforeDataElement){
        const previousElementValueRef = admin.database().ref('/groups/location/Items/' + itemId + '/mood/' + beforeDataElement + '/value');
        const previousElementVoteCountRef = admin.database().ref('/groups/location/Items/' + itemId + '/mood/' + beforeDataElement + '/votecount');

        previousElementValueRef.transaction(value => {
          return (parseInt(value || 0) - beforeDataValue>0?parseInt(value || 0) - beforeDataValue:0)
        })

        currentElementValueRef.transaction(value => {
          return parseInt(value || 0) + afterDataValue
        })

        previousElementVoteCountRef.transaction(votecount => {
          return (parseInt(votecount || 0) - 1>0?parseInt(votecount || 0) - 1:0)
        })

        currentElementVoteCountRef.transaction(votecount => {
          return parseInt(votecount || 0) + 1
        }) 

      } else {     
        currentElementValueRef.transaction(value => {
          return parseInt(value || 0) + afterDataValue
        })

        currentElementVoteCountRef.transaction(votecount => {
          return parseInt(votecount || 0) + 1
        })

        const voteCountRef = admin.database().ref('/groups/location/Items/' + itemId + '/mood/votecount');

        voteCountRef.transaction(votecount => {
          return parseInt(votecount || 0) + 1
        })  
      } 
    })
  })
  return groupMood })
```

Comment: What have you tried? There seems to be quite a bit of IO so if you could batch some of it, that would help.

Comment: I tried executing the `forEach` client-side passing the itemId argument to an http `onCall` function. It resulted in data consistency issues when I fired the method (I'm using vue js) client side several times.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are reading from the database inside a loop. If I had to guess, that is where most of the function's time is spent. Three thoughts:

1. **Before you do anything else**: You should check what is actually taking time, instead of relying on my hunch. You could use https://cloud.google.com/trace/ or simply add some `console.log()` statements to your code.
2. You could potentially read the whole `/groups/location/Items/` collection into a variable when the function starts. Then your code would simply read from that variable in the loop (fast) instead of reading from the database (slow). This is only possible if the `/groups/location/Items/` collection is small enough to fit into memory.
3. Instead of running one big job like the one above, you may be able to make a small calculation whenever `/users/***/groups/location/Items` is updated, and store it in a node in the database. I don't fully understand what your code does, but the pattern of many small calculations instead of a single big one has served me well in the past.

Best of luck!